# what happens if we input a single column to a neural net r model of multiple inputs?

Tags: r

I have a neural net model fitted in R using the fcast function.

```
fcast1<-fcast(data = ts1,f.number = 5,input = 4,layer = 3)
```

ts1 is a time series object.

The data has a single column in it and when I run the model, I get some sort of expected output. Why is this happening though I have given the input in the function as 4 nodes?
How does the neural net work for a 4 input model when I input a single column of data?